# Php for a bilingual site

Tags: php

Is it possible using php, for a user to click on a english/french toggle button, that would then read the current url, and match it to the french version of the page?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: PHP 5.3? http://devzone.zend.com/article/4799

Comment: Adel, I think you missed the point. The OP does not appear to be trying to localize specific pieces of data, but rather to change the language of the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

When the users clicks the button, populate a session variable with the selected language:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['language'] = 'FR'; // Or 'EN', etc
```

Then use templates to store your language-specific information. When you load the template, include the language code

```
// Load a template
Template::load( '<page_name>', $_SESSION['language'] );


// Where the `load()` method looks something like this:
public function load( $page_name, $language ) {
    // Construct the path to the template
    $file_handle = fopen( PATH_TO_TEMPLATES . $language . "/" . $page_name );

    // Do something with the template here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a quick response. I think my problem is that all the pages are developed. The english is in one folder, and the french in another. I have a utility section in the nav which is loaded as a php include.

My question is, is there a php script that on click will grab the current page url, and match it up to its french equivalent? I'm guessing we would need a list of variables for each page (example http://site.com/tools/calculator.php = http://site.com/tools/calculatrice.php) Does that make any sense?